# SQL Server: join 3 tables and sum() one column from each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables

```
-----------table1-------------
id    code    name    quantity
1     001     car1    1
2     002     car2    2
3     003     car3    3

-----------table2-------------
id    code    name    quantity
1     001     car1    1
2     002     car2    2

-----------table3-------------
id    code    name    quantity
1     001     car1    1
2     002     car2    2
3     004     car4    4
```

I want to join the three tables and take the total from quantity in SQL Server:

```
---------table-------
code    name    total
001     car1    3
002     car2    6
003     car3    3
004     car4    4
```

In MySql I try this and worked, but in SQL Server, I get me error :(

```
select 
    ID, CODE, NAME, sum(QUANTITY) as total 
from 
    (select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP1 
     union all
     select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP2 
     union all
     select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP3) x 
group by ID;
```

Comment: You to use all non aggregated columns of the `SELECT` clause in `GROUP BY`, like `group by ID, CODE, NAME`.

Comment: if you have time, write me an example because I do not understand

Comment: @ConstantinosAggelou - See the answer below.

Comment: Why do you have three different tables? One should do fine. (At least have a view that union all them together...)

Comment: In general, if you mention *I get an error* - you should **always** provide the full, complete and accurate error message(s) in your post since we really cannot read neither your screen, nor your mind. ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method would work in any database, if your `group by` fields match the unaggregated columns:

```
select CODE, NAME, sum(QUANTITY) as total
from (select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP1 union all
      select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP2 union all
      select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP3
     ) x
group by CODE, NAME;
```

The fact that it works in MySQL is due to a (mis)feature that allows any unaggregated columns in the `select` for an aggregation query.  In general, other databases do not support this non-standard syntax.

Comment: i have a mistake in MySQL code. it's CODE not ID

`select ID, CODE, NAME, sum(QUANTITY) as total
from (select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP1 union all
      select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP2 union all
      select ID, CODE, NAME, QUANTITY from AP3
     ) x
group by CODE;`

In MySql I take unique row per CODE.
In MSSQL I take duplicate row